# How to format ls command in raw terminal?

Tags: c, linux, shell, terminal

I've just started using raw mode in terminal (I am making a program that intercepts arrow keys).

When I run "ls" or "ls -l" through my program (a shell) it comes out horribly formatted. How can I manually set the formatting on raw mode so it comes out as it does in cooked mode?

Thanks for your help

Comment: just make sure you still have COLUMNS and LINES and TERM set appropriately within your script/program ?

Comment: Columns and Lines are the same, I can't find TERM within the "stty -a" command, is there somewhere else I can look?

Comment: When invoking the script/command (let's call it "program"), you can set the proper TERM by:    `TERM=something  program` (this will set "TERM=something" just for the duration of the program "program") (... unless that program's invocation also sets TERM! Then it's best to set it within the program itself). But maybe the problem is elsewhere: please tell us what is "horribly formatted": lines shorter than usual?

Comment: When I run the ls command in terminal (ubuntu) it will appear in neat columns. When I run it otherwise it is all over the place, they seem to be separated by tabs and might not have any carriage returns ('\r') or between each string in the output.

Comment: You should compare an invocation of `stty -a` in the shell **before** calling the script, and one **inside** the script, after you set it to raw. Chances are you set more things than just raw input? (`stty raw`, or `stty cbreak`, iirc ?)